# How to change time range for Grafana in case of iframe usage?

Tags: grafana

I use grafana iframe for my website:

```
<iframe src="https://...org/d-solo/.../...-dashbord?orgId=1&refresh=30s&panelId=8" width="450" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want to show chart for the last 24 hours or 1 week. Does any param exist something like `&rage=24h` or `&rage=W?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `from` and `to`, e.g.

```
&from=now-24h&to=now
```